# How to load an Excel add in and use a User Defined Type from that add in?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

In **add_in.xlam** I have:

```
Type Quantity
    i As Integer
end type

Sub show_quant(q as Quantiy)
    MsgBox(q.i)
end sub
```

In another workbook, I do:

```
Sub load_addin()
    Dim AI As Excel.AddIn
    Set AI = Application.AddIns.Add(Filename:="add_in.xlam")
    AI.Installed = True

    Dim q As Quantity
    show_quant(q)
End Sub
```

This doesn't work. Excel complains that the User defined type hasn't been defined yet.

So how *do* you declare variables of a type defined in an add in?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've ever been able to get something like that to work is to follow the instructions on this page: http://fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut08.htm Specifically, you have to give the vba project name a new name, and you need to add it as a reference, using that name.  The website explains it better.

Another page discussing the same thing: [calling-add-in-functions-from-vba](http://newtonexcelbach.wordpress.com/2011/04/16/calling-add-in-functions-from-vba/)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me without manually adding the reference:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim success As Boolean
    Dim myAddIn As AddIn

    ' Load and install new XLAM
    Set myAddIn = AddIns.Add(Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\path\to\myAddin.xlam")
    myAddIn.Installed = True

    ' Load known XLAM
    For Each myAddIn In AddIns
        If myAddIn.Name = "myAddin.xlam" Then
            myAddIn.Installed = False
            myAddIn.Installed = True
        End If
    Next
    Call AddReference(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\path\to\myAddin.xlam")
End Sub
```

I struggled because AddIns.Add needs an absolute path... But it seems to work!

---

Edit :
I also needed to use and call:

```
Sub AddReference(AddInPath As String)
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile (AddInPath)
End Sub
```

Source:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/accelerating_things/2010/09/16/loading-excel-add-ins-at-runtime/